# Is the spell from the third benefit of the War Caster feat still considered an opportunity attack for the Sentinel feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, opportunity-attack, reactions

The third benefit of the [War Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/war-caster) feat (PHB, p. 170) allows you to cast a spell when an enemy provokes an opportunity attack from you.  The spell must target only the provoking creature, and can only have a casting time of 1 action.

For the sake of abilities like the first benefit of Sentinel (which causes opportunity attacks to reduce a creature's speed to 0), **does my spell cast using the third benefit of War Caster still count** if it uses an attack?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### No, it's not an opportunity attack

The relevant phrasing in the [Sentinel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/sentinel) feat (PHB, p. 169-170) is:

> When you **hit a creature with an opportunity attack**, the creature's speed becomes 0 for the rest of the turn.

So the prerequisite for this feature is that you must hit a creature with an opportunity attack.

The relevant phrasing in the [War Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/war-caster) feat (PHB, p. 170) is:

> When a hostile creature's movement provokes an opportunity attack from you, **you can use your reaction to cast a spell at the creature, rather than making an opportunity attack**. The spell must have a casting time of 1 action and must target only that creature.

While the trigger is a situation that provides an opportunity attack, it specifically states that no opportunity attack is made, and you instead us a reaction for the spell casting. Thus, the Sentinel feat is not triggered.

Answer (score 5):

## No it is not.

The details explicitly say 'rather than making an opportunity attack'. However, either an opportunity attack or the players spell would use up the one reaction per turn.

PHB p170

> When a hostile creature's movement provokes an opportunity attack from you, you can use your reaction to cast a spell at the creature, rather than making an opportunity attack.