# If you have the War Caster feat and cast Booming Blade as a reaction, does it count as an opportunity attack for the UA Blade Mastery feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, opportunity-attack, unearthed-arcana

The third benefit of the Blade Mastery feat (from [Unearthed Arcana: Feats](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/UA-Feats-V1.pdf)) says:

> You master the shortsword, longsword, scimitar, rapier, and greatsword. You gain the following benefits when using any of them:
>
> [...]
>
> - When you make an opportunity attack with the weapon, you have advantage on the attack roll.

The third benefit of the [War Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/war-caster) feat (PHB, p. 170) says:

> - When a hostile creature's movement provokes an opportunity attack from you, you can use your reaction to cast a spell at the creature, rather than making an opportunity attack. The spell must have a casting time of 1 action and must target only that creature.

If you use your reaction to cast *booming blade*, does that count as making an opportunity attack as outlined by the Blade Mastery feat, since you are making a weapon attack as part of *booming blade*?

Comment: Related: [Is War Caster's spell still considered an Opportunity Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135252/is-war-casters-spell-still-considered-an-opportunity-attack)

Answer (score 23):

## You would not benefit from the third bullet point of *Blade Mastery*

Casting *Booming Blade*, or any other Spell, in place of your Opportunity Attack means you're not performing Opportunity Attack; you're simply casting a Cantrip as a Reaction.

It's worth noting how the *War Caster* feat words its feature:

> *... you can use your reaction to cast a spell at the creature, **rather than making an opportunity attack**...*

Even though Booming Blade involves the use of a melee weapon attack, it does not count as an Opportunity Attack when used this way, and features which normally benefit Opportunity Attacks would not apply to it.